# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load eposprint: findLibrary returned null

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am using Android Studio. I am using e-POS-Print.jar in my app. Whenever I run the code I get this error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.stc.printer.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:48)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load eposprint: findLibrary returned null
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
        at com.epson.eposprint.Print.<clinit>(Print.java:18)
        at com.stc.printer.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:48)
```

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    System.out.println("started");

    printerName = getString(R.string.printername_t81ii);
    language = Builder.MODEL_SOUTHASIA;

    //bellow is line no. 48
    Print newPrinter = new Print(getApplicationContext());
    try{
        newPrinter.openPrinter(deviceType, openDeviceName, enabled, interval);

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
        newPrinter = null;
    }

    setPrinter(newPrinter);
}
```

The sample project from Epson is having one native file with .so extension. But even if I remove that file from sample project it works.

I also tried adding that file to my project. But I am not able to add that file to my build path.

I also referred multiple answers from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037966/android-ndk-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-findlibrary-returned-null) but I am unsuccessful.

Comment: I tried same code in Eclipse. It is working. Android studio is not accepting .so (native library). I am finding out the work-around. Once found, I will post it here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After checking many sites, reading multiple answers, finally I figured out the solution.

Create folder tree as:

```
|---src
     |---main
           |---jniLibs
                  |---armeabi
                         |---nativeLib.so
```

Place your files under `armeabi` folder. And it will work.

[More about](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-how-to-handle-unsatisfied-link-error/) `java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror`

Comment: or x86 in case you use an emulator like Genymotion

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Need to check it. I used it in one of my application project. If your script is moving library to this path, and then follow build process, this should work.